# Key binding for image window ImageJ

Tags: java, imagej

I am using IJ library in Java. I use ImageWindow to display some images. I know that I can key binding a Jcomponent as a shortkey to execute some function. Can I key binding to ImageWindow so I can save the image when pressing ctrl+s?

Comment: Ctrl-S is already mapped to *File > Save* in ImageJ. Could you please give a specific code example illustrating your issue? Also, questions concerning ImageJ internals are best asked on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

Comment: I know but I am using IJ library in Java application instead of open ImageJ directly and neither creating a plugin.